# What is the right way to access the NumberSeq based on its name?

Tags: axapta

I created new Number Sequence in USMF/Organization administration/Common/Number sequences/Number sequences

Named New_NS

I find out lots of tutorials "how to use it" but I was not able to find any which will returns number sequence based on its name. So I end with

```
NumberSequenceTable NST;
Num num;
ttsbegin;
select forupdate NST where NST.NumberSequence == 'New_NS';
if(!NST.RecId)
{
     throw error('New_NS' + ' does not exist!');
}

num = NumberSeq::numInsertFormat(NST.NextRec, NST.Format);
NST.NextRec = NST.NextRec + 1;

if(NST.InUse == NoYes::No)
{
    NST.InUse = NoYes::Yes;
}

NST.update();
ttsCommit;
```

Is there some better way how to access New_NS based on its string name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode.

```
Num num;

ttsbegin;
num=NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode('New_NS').num();
ttscommit;
info(strfmt("Your number is %1.",num));
```

Comment: This returns me "Number sequence  does not exist." but I can see the Number sequence in USMF/Organization administration/Common/Number sequences/Number sequence. I try to use other values like RecID, seq. number, Number sequence code but I got "Number sequence  does not exist." everytime.

Comment: Make sure you execute the job in the same company for which the number sequence is defined.

Answer (score 1):

A number sequence is always connected with an extended data type. You can then access the number sequence using this extended data type. Also you do not need to access the `NumberSequenceTable` table itself, use instead the `NumberSeq` class to get a new number from the sequence. See [Generate Next Number Sequence by x++ code](http://theaxapta.blogspot.de/2013/06/generate-next-number-sequence-by-x-code.html)  for an example on how to use this class.

Comment: I seen that post you shared but I still do not know how to select number from 'New_NS'.